Rokoko retargeting Plugin - How to automatically match bones properly?

I want to retarget mixamo animations to my rig generated by rigify. But Rokoko plugin automatically all matches wrong bones(DEF-Something). So I have to fix about 50 amatures manually which is tedious, and I don't want to do these works whenever I retarget. Is there any way to make plugins target correct bones? I tried to hide DEF-Bones, but it was no use.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qHfUAniTM0
I followed this guy's tutorial. Thanks in advance for any advice.
